# iterating json data with Vue js v-for

Tags: json, vue.js, v-for

I have JSON data structured as follows:

```
Table - 
    0 -
          0 - "xyz"
          1 - "abc"
          **2 - 45**
          3 - "ab"
          ...
    1 -   ...
    2 -   ...
    3 -   ...
    ....
```

I am trying to get the value of the index 2 of the inner indexed data for every outer index. How do I do it with v-for. I have tried it this way but it is not working.

```
<table>
   <tr v-for = "row in rows">
      <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I am adding an abbr version of the actual data

```
{
  "Table":[
     [
       null,
       3,
       47,
       "new planning",
       "planning_new_0314",
       null,
       .....
     ],
     [ + ],
     [ + ],
     ...

   ]
}
```

I am getting the following error in the console window of IE 11 -
**Unable to get property '2' of undefined or null reference**

But I am seeing data in my page if I write this -

```
<tr v-for = "row in rows">
      <td>{{ row }}</td>
   </tr>
```

How do I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Could you show an abbreviated version of the actual JSON?

Comment: do you iterate through `youObject.Table` ?

Comment: @SLYcee yes I am iterating obj.Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code :

```
 <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
```

... is a good way to do it.

See this code :

```js
var object = {
  "Table":[
     [
       null,
       3,
       47,
       "new planning",
       "planning_new_0314",
       null,
       //.....
     ],
     [],
     [],
     //...

   ]
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
     table: object.Table
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <div v-for="row in table">
    {{ row[2] }}
  </div>
  
</div>
```

## -- UPDATED --

Maybe in your case `obj.Table` has a row without `index 2`. I test this case with the code above and it works.

But if you have problem with IE 11 try this code that verify that row and row[index] are not undefined (not sure that solve your problem...) :

```js
var object = {
  "Table":[
     [
       null,
       3,
       47,
       "new planning",
       "planning_new_0314",
       null,
       //.....
     ],
     [1,2,3,4],
     [1],
     //...

   ]
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
     table: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTableDatas: function() {
      this.table = object.Table;
    },
    getRowIndex: function(row, index) {
      //you can/should replace "'!!no index ' + index" by empty string !
      return ((typeof row !== 'undefined') && (typeof row[index] !== 'undefined'))
             ? row[index] : '!!no index ' + index;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
Comment : The third row has no index "2".<br/>
  <button @click="getTableDatas">Get table datas</button>
  <div v-for="row in table">
    {{ getRowIndex(row, 2) }}
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting this is the console window - unable to get property '2' of undefined or null reference

Comment: but if I do this then I am seeing data in my page - {{ row }}

Comment: @sagarmajumdar ok i updated my code. Use `{{ getRowIndex(row, 2) }}` and not `{{ row[2] }}`